# 2 списка делители

Tags: python

Реализовать функцию которая создаст новый список из элементов первого списка, взятых по одному разу, таких, для которых во втором списке есть делители данного числа (числа, отличные по модулю от самого числа, а также 0 и 1)
Например

```
({ 7, 12, 0, 8, -21, 145, 100, 17 }, { 4, 3, 0, -1, -8, 29, 7 }) 
→ { 12, 8, -21, 145, 100 }
```

Comment: Покажите, что вы попытались сделать и что у вас получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first = [int(i[:-1]) for i in input().split()]
second = [int(i[:-1]) for i in input().split()]

ans = []

for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i != 0 and j != 0 and abs(j) != 1 and i % j == 0 and abs(i) != abs(j):
            ans.append(i)
            break

print(ans)
```